# Stackoverflow: efficiently getting order of smallest to largest in dataframe per row

Tags: python, pandas

This dataframe has got hundreds of thousands of rows, so it does not seem like I can afford to use `apply()`. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          1         2         3         4         5         6
         Ax        Ax        Ax        Ax        Ax        Ax
      delta     delta     delta     delta     delta     delta
0  0.011475  0.000244  0.009277  0.003174  0.002197  0.003418
1  0.011515  0.000529  0.009481  0.003215  0.002157  0.003621
2  0.011556  0.000326  0.009440  0.003255  0.002116  0.003581
3  0.011556  0.000326  0.009440  0.003255  0.002116  0.003581
4  0.011556  0.000326  0.009440  0.003255  0.002116  0.003581
5  0.011556  0.000326  0.009196  0.003255  0.002360  0.003581
6  0.011353  0.000366  0.009155  0.003296  0.002319  0.003540
7  0.011353  0.000610  0.009155  0.003296  0.002563  0.003540
8  0.011312  0.000570  0.008952  0.003255  0.002604  0.003581
9  0.011312  0.000570  0.008952  0.003255  0.002604  0.003581
```

I would like to (efficiently) determine the order per-row from smallest to largest. Obviously, I can use `apply` to determine this per row, but I would like to vectorize this if at all possible.

The precise format of the output is not particularly important; but I need to know, per row, what the order of columns is. So, for example, row 0 would be `[5, 2,  4, 6, 3, 1]`.

Would it be possible to reduce the dataframe to something like the following:

```
0  (1, 0.011475)  (2, 0.000244)  (3, 0.009277)  (4, 0.003174)  (5, 0.002197)  (6, 0.003418)
```

and then sort that per-row - without using apply? Is there any way to 're-tuplize' the values?

I'm aware of `idxmax`, is there something similar to get the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it row-based ranking you want?

```
df

      0         1         2
0 -0.782973  0.601814 -0.154782
1  0.718408 -0.882676 -1.008940
2  0.144548  0.284833 -1.738883
3  0.754866  0.753008  1.118544
4  0.968328 -0.177870 -1.283252

df.rank(method='first', axis=1).astype(int)
    0  1  2
0  1  3  2
1  3  2  1
2  2  3  1
3  2  1  3
4  3  2  1
```

Depending on the data, you may want to adjust the method used, and if you want to cast to int at the end.